# Ubuntu 19.04 is stuck at loading screen

Tags: dual-boot

I installed ubuntu 19.04 on my hp laptop using dual boot without any problem , the other os is windows 10. But once I try to boot my pc using ubuntu, the problem starts , I see only the dots happily loading which is so determined to frustrate me every single time I try to boot. Tried changing my time and date in windows in sync with ubuntu after reading it in a blog. It worked but for only once. Tried some stuff in recovery menu like enabling networking and putting some commands as instrusted in some articles in vain.  Any other help will be appreciated. Thanks.
Ps : I'm new to linux.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings and welcome to Linux.
Sometimes things can be a little frustrating for beginners, but believe me, it's worth persevering with.
Unfortunately, it can be most difficult to fix problems that occur before your OS boots. It's also not clear if your problem is because of dual boot or some other issue.

- Try pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> when the UEFI/BIOS has finished or has almost finished loading. You should see various boot options, including recovery mode. [Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)
- If you're able to get Ubuntu to boot again, modify your config file `custom.conf` by uncommenting the seventh line `#Wayland = false` [Full description here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165210/116041)
- If you can't boot at all, try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> when stuck on the splash screen. You should be able to login from the command line. At this point, you can follow the above instructions, although you'll have to edit the config file from within the command line session. This is a bit lengthy to explain here if you don't know how. I'll let you research it yourself
- You can try updating your device drivers. Once again, this is much harder to do if you can't boot Ubuntu. As you've stated you have managed this at least once, you'll have to get that far and then go through the Software & Updates application. [For example like this](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-update-the-drivers-in-ubuntu)

Good luck