# Old Arch Linux won't boot anymore with Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 19.10

Aside from Ubuntu 19.10, I have an old version version of Arch Linux and Windows 7 installed.

After selecting Arch Linux in Grub it won't boot anymore. The screen merely turns blank. I also don't see the HDD activity led burn, so probably nothing is loaded. Arch Linux did boot when I was still using Ubuntu 19.04. Windows 7 does boot.

What I tried:

1. Boot Arch without 'splash quiet' in the hope to see where it fails. However, nothing is displayed, just the blank screen.
2. Boot with `nosplash debug --verbose`. Still nothing.
3. Boot with `nomodeset`. Still nothing.
4. Try to remove `add_efi_memmap` kernel parameter (tip from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Boot_freezes). In my case, the kernel parameter isn't even there.

The command `sudo update-grub` does find all OSes installed.

According to https://askubuntu.com/a/1182691 Grub has become a mess in Ubuntu 19.10. Don't know in as far that is true.

I do suspect it is a Grub issue. I see three options left:

1. Suggestion from one of you guys, e.g. edit a Grub file, pass a parameter, etc. Suggestions that do not lead to irreversible changes.
2. Wait for an Ubuntu upgrade, hopefully fixing this Grub issue. Although I would like to access Arch, there's no great rush, so I consider this a viable option.
3. Run Boot-Repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) Never used this tool before, so I am slightly hesitant to use it, it may aggravate matters.

Your advice?

Comment: I think you should use Boot-Repair as the first resort, not the last one. IIRC you can also use it to reinstall GRUB. If it does not solve your problem automatically, please [edit] your question to include the Boot-Info URL generated by Boot-Repair.

Comment: Tried Boot-Repair. It did not fix the problem. Instead my Grub menu now shows duplicate entries. Fortunately Ubuntu and Windows 7 still boot. Anyway, I decided not to mess with this any longer, it's not worthwhile. Just posted this comment for any future reader.